# Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'chart'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I have the following component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'chart',
    templateUrl: 'app/comps/chart.html',
    providers: [],
})
export class ChartComp {

    constructor() {
        this.options = {
            title : { text : 'simple chart' },
            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
            }]
        };
    }
    options: Object;
}
```

and module file

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts'))],

declarations: [Chart],
exports: [Chart]})

export class ModuleFile {
....
}
```

and html file

```html
<chart [options]="options"></chart>
```

Then I have an example page, which implements this component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'example-chart',
    templateUrl:'app/comps/chart/example-chart.html',
    providers: [],
})


export class ExampleChart{

    constructor(

    ) {
        this.options = {
            title : { text : 'simple chart' },
            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
            }]
        };
    }
    options: Object;
}
```

and html

```html
<chart [options]="options"></chart>
```

where `options` is the configuration passed to the html. But not sure why I am getting this weird error

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'chart'.
1. If 'chart' is an Angular component and it has 'options' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'chart' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I tried adding `@Input` for the options. Then I get a DI error. Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make it an input to be able to bind to it using property-binding:

```
@Input()
options: Object;
```

Comment: I tried that Gunter, But I get another error `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: DI Error
Error: DI Error
    at NoProviderError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:3002/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:992:33)`

Comment: Hard to tell where this new error comes from. You definitely need `@Input()` though if you want to bind to it.